# installed mysql using yum but mysqld dowsnt start: Fedora 16

Tags: fedora, mysql, database

i installed mysql mysql-server and mysql-libs ...
after installation i thought to start the mysql service using command
systemctl start mysqld.service
Failed to issue method call: Unit mysqld.service failed to load: Invalid argument. See system logs and 'systemctl status mysqld.service' for details.
systemctl status mysqld.service
this said that it had an invalid argument

then i changed the content of mysqld.service with this

File: /etc/systemd/system/mysqld.service

```
[Unit]
Description=MySQL database server
After=syslog.target
After=network.target

[Service]
User=mysql
Group=mysql

ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
ExecStop=/bin/kill -15 $MAINPID
PIDFile=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

# We rely on systemd, not mysqld_safe, to restart mysqld if it dies
Restart=always

# Place temp files in a secure directory, not /tmp
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

now i found that the error for invalid argument was resolved and mysqld.service was loaded
but not enabled ... 
using systemctl start mysqld.service worked fine ... it workedddd!

but then enabling it 
systemctl enable mysqld.service or service mysqld start did not do anything but the curdor kept on blinking after i pressed enter ...

now the thing is that for this f16 i wasted my HDD space for development work and i cannot figure out a way ... please somebody help